# Android Alert Dialog Background Issue API 11+

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-dialog

I create a `AlertDialog` with the code below.
For some reason I'm getting an extra background (see pic) on Honeycomb and above.
The code **crashes** fine for anything below honeycomb.
`MyCustomDialog` is simply `Theme.Dialog` for < API-11 and `Theme.Holo.Dialog` for API-11 and up.

1. Any idea why I'm getting the extra background?
2. Any idea why it crashes for API < 11? It works fine if I remove the Theme.

**Update** figured out the answer to Question #2. Seems the constructor `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)` was introduced in API 11. My fix was simply to change the line to:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 11)? new AlertDialog.Builder(this) : new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.JumpDialog);
```

I still need help with Question #1

[image]

```
private Dialog setupKeyBoardDialog() {
    if (mContact.getLocaleId() != -1) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyCustomDialog);
        builder.setTitle("Keyboards");

        mKeyboardLayouts = new KeyboardLayoutGroup();
        mKeyboardLayouts.layoutNames = new CharSequence[(int) jni.getNumKeyLayouts()];
        mKeyboardLayouts.layoutValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jni.getNumKeyLayouts(); i++) {
            mKeyboardLayouts.layoutNames[i] = jni.LayoutInfoForIndex(i).getName();
            mKeyboardLayouts.layoutValue.add(i, (int) jni.LayoutInfoForIndex(i).getLocale_id());
        }

        final int selectedItem = mKeyboardLayouts.layoutValue.indexOf(mContact.getLocaleId());

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mKeyboardLayouts.layoutNames, selectedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                mContact.setLocaleId(mKeyboardLayouts.layoutValue.get(item));
                mContactsDB.saveContact(mContact, true);

                dialog.dismiss();
                initializeSettingsList();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int arg1) {
                dialogBox.cancel();
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the R.style.JumpDialog code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured out the answers

1. AlertDialog has it's on static constants for each theme in the
   AlertDialog class and it does not take the standard theme. when I
   replaced `R.style.MyTheme` or `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog`
   with [`AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) the code worked just
   fine.
2. Seems the constructor `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int
   theme)` was introduced in API 11. My fix was simply to change the
   line to:

   ```
   final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   } else {
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.JumpDialog);
   }
   ```

Comment: From 1.6 on, you should use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT instead
because Build.VERSION.SDK is deprecated.

Comment: updated the answer to remove the deprecated api and hardcoded api level

Comment: so "Integer.parseInt" no needed anymore

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use `new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.JumpDialog))` instead of `new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.JumpDialog)`

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a way to customize the dialog theme without having to stick with the default ones (as in the accepted solution), starting with Lollipop it seems that the extra background has been finally removed. So, now you can create a theme inheriting from the default one (example with AppCompat):

```
<!-- default theme for L devices -->
<style name="SelectionDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_text_color_holo_light</item>
</style>
<!-- theme for Pre-L devices -->
<style name="SelectionDialog.PreL">
    <!-- remove the dialog window background -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And instantiate your builder with this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity(),                
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ?
                    R.style.SelectionDialog :
                    R.style.SelectionDialog_PreL);
```

Of course this could also be done with resource folders (`values/` and `values-v21/`).